# Vimperator: Follow hint in new tab and switch to it

Tags: vimperator, iceweasel

I am trying to find a strategy in the Vimperator-logic for opening a link to a new tab and switch to it immediately.
I guess this might be a [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

My first approach would be to start off with a `:command` sequence. Unfortunately `F` - Follow hint in background tab - has no equivalent in the command mode. The best solution for me would be without any change in default behaviour whatsoever.

Another approach might be to combine the default `F` with switching to next tag `gt`. This would have to include to pass the parameter for `F`, say 10 for the tenth link of the document. Unfortunately `F10gt` does open the tenth link but without switching to the newly opened tab.

A third approach does come to mind when using focus elements: `;y10` yank the destination link, `:tabopen` + paste clipboard content.

Any ideas of what is doable and the easiest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality exists as a mode of the hint function. Pressing **;t**
will produce the desired result. If you want to map it you can also access the javascript directly.

```
:js hints.show("t")
```